# How to run two functions at a time in c++ in a standard way?

Tags: c++

I made an alarm clock and set the alarm time for the clock.
Whenever the alarm time meets the clock time, it pauses the clock time for some time.
How can I run these two functions at a time using a standard way in c++?

```
void clock()
{
//Clock Time Function
}

void alarmTime()
{
//Alarm Function
}
```

Comment: how are these functions running? did you implement a clock from the ground up, or are you simply setting an alarm with whatever scheduling facilities the underlying OS provides?

Comment: I'm new to C++. The program will ask the user to enter the alarm time. whenever the alarm time condition meets the time, it'll execute the alarm function. I've made clock by incrementing sconds.

Comment: Multithreading is overkill for such a simple task.  Poll the clock function, and if the time matches the alarm time, call the alarm function.  If you introduce multithreading, the necessary synchronization will likely make the alarm time less accurate than a single thread polling.

Comment: @Chad It's probably overkill, but if he's doing this as a practice exercise it isn't a terrible way to learn how to multithread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer is multithreading.  When clock time meets alarm time, fork a thread to the alarm function.  If using C++11, you can use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).  If not, you can use [`pthread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html).

Answer (score 2):

Unix - http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?alarm+2
Windows - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Either should do the trick depending on your poison